# Margin-right on css is not working in my div

Tags: html, css

If you want to look at it, it’s [onceuponatheme2.tumblr.com](http://onceuponatheme2.tumblr.com/). Below is the CSS for it. I’m trying to make the icons on the bottom be 5px from the right, but still appear as though it’s on top of the double border around the noticebox div.

```css
#noticebox{
    position:fixed;
    width:200px; /*width*/
    z-index:99999999999999999999;
    height:auto;
    left:90px; /*how far from the right*/
    top:90px; /*how far from the top*/
    color:#000000; /*text colour*/
    background-color:#ffffff; /*background colour*/
    border:1px solid #000000; /*border width and colour*/
    border-width:3px;   
    border-style:double;
    text-align:center; /*text align*/
    padding:5px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
#noticebox a{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-style:italic; /*italic links before hover*/
    letter-spacing:1px; /*distance between letters*/
}
#noticebox a:hover{
    font-style:normal;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#blogtitle{
    font-size:20px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:-25px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-right:3px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    font-family: 'Berkshire Swash', cursive;
    text-transform:none;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    background:{color:background};
    color:{color:text};
    position:absolute;
}
#description{
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
#links{
    width:120px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    margin-bottom:-25px;
    margin-right:5px;
    background:{color:background};
    position:relative;
}
#links a{
    color:{color:text};
}
```

Comment: if any of the below worked, please support, just to find the right anser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add this style in `#links` class

```
float: right;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `position:relative` to `position:absolute` for #links, and add `right: 5px;` You can then remove `margin-right: 5px`

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you have wrote inside `#links` is perfectly fine. Only thing you need to add is a `left:60px` in the `#links`. My personal advise is to reduce the use of `float` property.
So finally you `#links` is look like,

`#links {
    width:120px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    margin-bottom:-25px;
    margin-right:5px;
    background:{color:background};
    position:relative;
    left: 60px;
}`

You can adjust the div by adjusting the `left` value.

Hope this will solve your issue.